# Can you use nameof when hidden by in scope member?

Tags: c#, nameof

Consider the following legacy code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Blah(string frob)
    {
        if (frob == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("frob");
    }

    public string nameof()
    {
        //boring code
    }
}
```

Now imagine part of this code is being refactored, and we want to refactor `Blah` in the following way:

```
public void Blah(string frob)
{
    if (frob == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(frob)); //nameof contextual keyword
}
```

This parser will not choose the contextual keyword `nameof` and will resolve to the private method `nameof` giving a compile time error (no existing overload). Why? I would understand this if the method was `nameof(object o)`.

Is there someway I can make the compiler resolve to the inbuilt `nameof`? Do I need to refactor the code renaming the method?

The example above is a very simplified scenario, in truth the `nameof` method is used extensively in reflection and it will take time and effort to make sure the renaming has been done correctly everywhere.

Comment: Why is `nameof` not at least named `NameOf`?

Comment: @Servy I have no idea. The whole code is a horrible mess, that is the least of all although they could have chosen any other word to case incorrectly

Comment: Well, doing a global find & replace of `nameof` by `NameOf` might be the best solution if you can update all the code. Then you remplace all `NameOf` that do not compile by `nameof`... Obviously before doing that you have to push your old code to your version control system. Assuming that your custom `nameof` never have any argument, it should works relatively well.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no way to resolve that conflict without renaming the poorly named function that does not even follow .NET convention of Pascal casing. This is a way to go in the other direction by prepending an identifier with @ as in `@int`. My guess is that they have done it that way so that existing code would not break.

Comment: What is the actual purpose of your existing `nameof` function and how much it is used in your code and how? Maybe you might even want to reconsider the whole thing...

Answer (score 8):

> This parser will not choose the contextual keyword nameof and will resolve to the private method nameof giving a compile time error (no existing overload). Why?

"Why" questions are vague; I'm going to assume the question means "what are some design considerations taken into account when designing features like this?"

A high-order consideration when creating a new contextual keyword is to *ensure that no existing program changes meaning when compiled in the new compiler*.  For example, when I wrote the code to add `var` in C# 3, we were careful to ensure that

```
class var { public implicit operator var(int x) { ... } }
...
var y = 3;
```

assigns type `var` to `y`, and not `int`. Even though programs like this are very unlikely, we want to break *no one at all*.

Similarly, the syntax for `yield return` was `yield return` and not merely `yield` because *no program ever had `yield return` in it.  But lots of programs might have said `yield(123);`

Similarly the `await` operator only is meaningful when inside an `async` method, and `from` and `select` and so on are meaningful inside query comprehensions.

Thus `nameof` must mean *an identifier named `nameof`* if one is in scope, and not the operator. Note that C# does not attempt to backtrack. It does not say "well, its in scope, but that causes an overload resolution error, so I'm going to backtrack and assume that it is the keyword..."  No no no, that is terrible reasoning. **An identifier `nameof` is in scope and therefore this is almost certainly a pre-C# 6 program**.  The 99.9% likelihood is that *every* use of `nameof` in that program intends to refer to the identifier.

A basic design principle of C# is "if something looks weird, *tell the developer so they are aware of the problem*."  You are now thoroughly aware that there is a serious problem in your program, and now you can attempt to fix it. C# is not designed to find *any possible interpretation of your program that compiles, no matter how bizarre and unlikely*.

Comment: Totally agree, the why was more frustration than anything else. I was meaning to edit the question because that answer was particularly obvious. I wanted to know if there was a workaround but I guess there isn't unless you do something clever with expressions and a helper class where a method `nameof` isnt in scope. Not really worth it, we'll just make it all harder for the next poor soul that has to deal with this code. We'll have to rename the method and spend more time and effort than planned fixing up this mess. Better now than later.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that reflection code search for `nameof` in a class for something that might be somehow similar to a serialization framework...

In that is the case, maybe the best temporary solution would be to update that code to first search a function `NameOf` and if that one does not exist search the legacy `nameof`.

That way, you would be able to find your code one class at a time.

If you want to do a full fix at once and assuming that your custom `nameof` function never take any arguments, then the best solution is probably to rename all `nameof` once to `NameOf` (or any other name you like) and then fix compilation error when `nameof` should be used. This would make sense if you have a lot of code and are just starting to use the `nameof` operator.

In any case, it was a bad idea not to follow .NET naming convention particularly for short name like that that might become a keyword at some point.

Maybe it would also be a good idea to have code review so that those that write bad code fix it before the leave the company.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of whether or not you could force the code to use the nameof keyword instead of the built in function, you really shouldn't be using a keyword as a method name. Rename the nameof method.

Comment: you are overlooking the fact that the question states that this is legacy code that existed before nameof became a keyword.

Comment: He said 'Do I need to refactor the code renaming the method?' so I assumed that renaming was a possibility even if it was legacy.